# Trying to get import to work

Tags: html, import

Inspired by [this html5rocks post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/), I thought I'd try link rel="import".
In the console, I get:

```
yay!
Loaded import: http://www.example.com/HelloWorld.htm
```

But I don't get "Hello World!" on the page.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function supportsImports() {
  return 'import' in document.createElement('link');
}

if (supportsImports()) {
  console.log('yay!')
} else {
  console.log('boo!')
}
function handleLoad(e) {
    console.log('Loaded import: ' + e.target.href);
}
function handleError(e) {
    console.log('Error loading import: ' + e.target.href);
}
</script>
<link rel="import" href="HelloWorld.htm" onload="handleLoad(event)" onerror="handleError(event)">
</body>
</html>
```

And HelloWorld.htm contains:

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Edit:

In the console, I can see that <h1>Hello World!</h1> is inside the link tag as another #document, complete with <html><head></head></body>.

Comment: The file has been imported. That doesn't mean its contents are going to be dumped into the current page. For starters, *where* should the content appear, assuming you already have some content on the page...?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what import is supposed to do. Are you saying that it has something to do with the shadow dom instead of just a simple import or include statement?

Comment: AFAIK it's mostly related to WebComponents; though there are probably other uses for it.

Comment: Oh OK. I found the htm5rocks article by Googling html include. I just need the simplest way to include the same file into all my web pages. This file is not a .css or .js file. It contains all my setup lines of code like my links to all my css files and all my script references and my title tag and my meta statements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the same HTML5Rocks post, when you import an HTML resource, it is accessible as a JavaScript object. Specifically, a `Document`:

```
var myImport = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;
document.querySelector(/* get the element we want here */).appendChild(myImport.body);
```

That does contradict somewhat with the beginning of the article, which balks at using JavaScript to load HTML, but at least it uses much less JavaScript (the kind that can, perhaps, fit in a browser tag) and certainly is not subject to the CORS restrictions that AJAX has to deal with.